# Workaround for replacing quote mark in Word 2003 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA code in Word 2003 that replaces some XML entities. The following code still replaces the `\u2018` to `&apos;` despite the `Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False` at the beginning, instead of only the `\u0027`.

Any advice on why is this behavior and any known solution/workaround?

The code:

```
Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop

    .Text = "&"
    .Replacement.Text = "&amp;"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    .Text = Chr(34)
    .Replacement.Text = "&quot;"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    .Text = ChrW(&H27)            '  "'"
    .Replacement.Text = "&apos;"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jsotola I don't see why that is, since when you type, this option affects the single quotes as well (such as `\u2018`).

Comment: what about the curly quotes?  does it replace them?

Comment: Good point, it does, I tested it now. Actually I had a workaround in place that I actually replace the curly quote marks (`\u201C-\u201F`) and then I do the replacement on the `&quot;` and finally I change all the curly ones back to the characters. For some reason I thought `&apos;` is okay without this workaround, but I guess it is not. Any idea why it does not work when the option is actually turned off?

Comment: ran some tests of the find command ... search for `straight` quotes finds all quotes (same with apostrophe) ... search for curly quotes finds only curly quotes (left curly finds only left ... etc) same with curly apostrophe

Comment: i think that the AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes option only affects `replace as you type` function